# Click TModel3D from a FMX 3D application

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey

Any update on this ?

https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/23654593/onclick-event-for-tmodel3d?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=it&_x_tr_hl=it&_x_tr_pto=sc

for summary i need to click a Tmodel3D from my viewport, but i'm unable to get the click handle.
the TModel£d has a native onclick event but do not work..

any help ?

on the link there is a solution with TRectangle but do not work for me

Comment: moreover i observe that Trectangle is a TControl3D, and the onclick event work there. TModel3D is a descendant of TControl3D but it doesn't there.

Comment: i found a solution, i should delete the question ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of deleting, edit the question to be more clear and then post an answer.

Comment: Make sure TModel3D.HitTest is set to receive OnClick